# Em um elemento que tem Duas ou mais Classes, como é definido a prioridade?

Tags: html, css

Basicamente tenho duas classes que tem uma propriedade em comum (exemplo "color"), assim a propriedade da Classe 1 sempre sobrepõe o da Classe 2, ai gostaria de saber a lógica ou alguma forma de forçar a Classe que eu quero ter prioridade sobre a outra em um mesmo elemento.

HTML:

```
 <div class="Classe1 Classe2"> 
      Exemplo de Elemento 
      </div>
```

CSS:

```
   .Classe1{color:red;}

   .Classe2{color:blue;}
```

Comment: Você está fazendo isso apenas com html e css ? Se sim, você pode usar o ["!important"](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_important.asp), mas se quer tornar isso dinâmico e mudar a classe baseado em condições você precisará de javascript/jquery/typescript... De alguma linguagem de programação.

Answer (score 3):

Ele sempre irá manter a última alteração de classe.

CSS é lido de cima para baixo, então ele aplica o primeiro estilo no elemento e depois aplica o outro sobrescrevendo o anterior.

Você pode usar [especificidades](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) para garantir a alteração (mais indicado) ou adicionar um `!important` no estilo que necessitar.

Exemplo:

```
div:not(.Classe1) {
  color: blue;
}
```